# Retrieving element through array efficiently

Tags: javascript

This is one element in an array holding about 50 others.

```
var fiftyplanets = [{
   "rowid": 1,
   "Host name": "HD 224693",
   "Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]": 0.71,
   "Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]": 12.1,
   "Distance [pc]": 94.07
}, ...]
```

I've got 5 variables range1 through range5 that filter the array into five parts with each 10 elements like so:

```
var range = (array, start, end) =>
      fiftyplanets.filter((element, index)=>index>=start && index <= end);

var range1 = range([fiftyplanets],0,9);
```

Lastly, upon user input, this *should* switch between which element with the by the user seen and clicked on "Host name" should be the one element to be retrieved.

```
  if (value == range1[4]["Host name"]) {
        var name = range1[4]["Host name"];
        var dist = range1[4]["Distance [pc]"];
        var mass = range1[4]["Planet Mass or M*sin(i)[Jupiter mass]"];
        var radi = range1[4]["Planet Radius [Jupiter radii]"];
  }
```

I could make 49 other if statements like that but how do I trim that code down so `value` checks through all elements in the range with the same ""Host name", and then retrieve the other information like dist and mass pertaining to that?

Comment: why not use an array instead of single variables? and for the last part, why not use th object, you already have?

Comment: this is my dumbed down version approach, as i'm fairly new to programming. This makes the most sense for me right now without losing grasp of how my code works

Comment: but in this case you have to declare lots of variables, without really need for it. an array keeps all grouped objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just an answer of getting a part of the array

Instead of this function expression

```
var range = (array, start, end) => fiftyplanets.filter((element, index) => index >= start && index <= end);
```

you could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get a copy of a part of an array

```
var range = (array, start, end) => array.slice(start, end + 1);
```

Comment: So with this, if I wanted to retrieve an element number that's been assigned to value in say.. range 0-9, it should look a bit like this? `fiftyplanets.slice(0, 9 + 1)[value]["Host name"]` ?

Comment: you get with `slice` an array not a single element of the array.